# How can I create a bar graph dynamically using data in JS

Tags: javascript, graph

Can someone please suggest how I can create a bar graph, dynamically in Javascript. Below is the design that I am trying to achieve. I did come across [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart), but couldn't figure out ways to acheive the below deisgn style.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[D3.js](https://d3js.org/) is a long-standing and very popular solution for all kinds of dynamic charts and graphs.

Check out the [gallery](https://observablehq.com/@d3/gallery) and search for the word bar to find examples that might fit your use case.

You might also just google "d3js" and words relevant to your problem. In your case, this is really a type of "gauge", and when I search "d3js" and "gauge", a few examples come up that may be closer to your data type, though maybe not exactly in that style.

D3.js is very configurable though. If you don't find something out-of-the-box, you should have the tools to make it work.